# wpf Accessing xaml object created by LoadComponent() from ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a method that will need access to a xaml object.

I know this breaks the MVVM convention, but there are other circumstances that prevents me from simply using a data binding.

this is the xaml code

```
<Page x:Class="RainforestExcavator.cs1.UI.TestCasePage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RainforestExcavator.cs1.UI"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
  Title="TestCasePage">

<Grid>
    <TreeView x:Name="treeView"/>
</Grid>
```

I have a ViewModel that needs to populate the treeView.

```
    public class TestSuiteViewModel :  INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public TestSuiteViewModel()
        {
            LoadData();
            LoadCommand();
            Messenger.Messenger.Default.Register<string>(this, OnPlanPopulated,"PlanUpdated");
        }

        private void OnPlanPopulated(string selectedPlan)
        {  
        methodThatWillPopulateTheTreeView(selectedPlan, treeView)
        }
}
```

there is a messenger class that will trigger the "OnPlanPopulated" method when the selectedPlan is populated.

I am having trouble doing this.

Namely, I am unable to access the TestCasePage object that is created on Initialize().

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Post code that tries to access 'TestCasePage' object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able the access the TreeView or the Page in your view model you need to pass in a reference to it. Instead of sending a simple string as the payload using the Messenger you could define a type that can carry the both the string and a reference to the TreeView/Page:

```
public class ThePayLoad
{
  public string SelectedPlan {get; set;}
  public TreeView TreeView { get; set; }
}
```

You then use this type as the type argument of the messenger's Send and Register methods;

**View:**

```
 Messenger.Messenger.Default.Send<ThePayLoad>( new ThePayLoad() { SelectedPlan = "selected plan...", TreeView = treeView} );
```

**View Model:**

```
public TestSuiteViewModel()
{
        LoadData();
        LoadCommand();
        Messenger.Messenger.Default.Register<ThePayLoad>(this, OnPlanPopulated,"PlanUpdated");
}

private void OnPlanPopulated(ThePayLoad payload)
{  
    methodThatWillPopulateTheTreeView(payLoad.SelectedPlan, payLoad.treeView)
}
```